# Is it correct to say that the eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix A is unique up to taking multiples of the eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the notes I'm working through it mentions that the eigenvalue decomposition $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$ of a matrix A is unique apart from the signs of the eigenvectors (the columns of Q).

Considering the fact that if $q_i$ is an eigenvalue of A with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ then so is any multiple of $u_i$(i.e. any vector parallel to $u_i$
.

Based off these two facts, I'd like to check that the following :deduction" is true:
The eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix is unique up to taking multiples of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes, what you're saying is true, Given any non-defective matrix,the eigenvectors $q_i$ are usually normalized, but they need not be. A non-normalized set of n eigenvectors, $v_i$ can also be used as the columns of Q. That can be understood by noting that the magnitude of the eigenvectors in Q gets canceled in the decomposition by the presence of $Q^{−1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I would say the correct statement is: "The eigendecomposition of a matrix is unique up to taking multiples of eigenvectors."
Eigenvalue decomposition is not so common.